# parsing system GTA V

Tags: python

```
    parse = "https://support.rockstargames.com/ru/servicestatus"
    headers = {"User-Agent": "?)"}

    page = requests.get(parse, headers = headers)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "html.parser")
    servers_blocks = soup.select('#status visible > div > flex services > div > div')
    serveronline = ''   
    for server in servers_blocks:
        serveronline += server.text.strip().replace('\n/ ','/')
        serveronline +='\n--------\n\n'
```

Good day. Faced with ignorance of what exactly needs to be parsed in the element code. I need to display the entire table at once, that is, the state of the rdr, GTAV servers, etc. But I don't understand how to do it.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be requesting to status URL not scraping, as it's easy.

The URL is `https://support.rockstargames.com/ru/services/status.json`.

```py
import requests

r = requests.get("https://support.rockstargames.com/ru/services/status.json").json()

data = {}

for i in r['statuses']:
    data[i['name']] = {}
    for x in i['services_platforms']:
        data[i['name']][x['name']] = x['service_status']['status']
data['last_updated'] = r['updated']

print(data)

#Output

{'General': {'Alert': 'Активен'},
 'Grand Theft Auto Online': {'PC': 'Активен',
                             'PS3': 'Активен',
                             'PS4': 'Активен',
                             'Xbox 360': 'Активен',
                             'Xbox One': 'Limité'},
 'Red Dead Online': {'PC': 'Активен',
                     'PS4': 'Активен',
                     'Stadia': 'Активен',
                     'Xbox One': 'Активен'},
 'Rockstar Games Launcher': {'Authentication': 'Активен',
                             'Cloud Services': 'Активен',
                             'Downloads': 'Активен',
                             'Store': 'Активен'},
 'Social Club': {'All Features': 'Активен'},
 'Support': {'Alert': 'Активен'},
 'last_updated': '13 августа 2020 г., 16:59:58 GMT+05:30'}
```